# How to call a method from a dynamically instantiated class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, instance

I'm dinamically instantiating a class, but I want to know if there's a way to call a method from this instance, thanks

**Code**:

```php
if(class_exists($class_name)){
  
  $class = new $class_name;
  $class.method();

}
```

```php
class foo implements bar {

  public function method(): void {
      echo "method called";
  }

}
```

**Expected Result:**

Call the method from the object

**Actual Result:**
Error: Call to undefined function method()

Comment: Can you show the code from your dynamic class which results in the error.

Comment: It's arrow syntax instead of a period character, like `$class->method();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php use the arrow to call the class's function.

```
$class.method();
```

should be

```
$class->method();
```

alternatively if your method is declared as static you can use it like so

```
foo::method();
```

Comment: For static calls, the method also has to be declared as static.

Comment: good point ill add it